# Big issue in IE 7, WordPress pages wont scroll

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, wordpress

Well WordPress is pretty key to my website, I've had many a problem with IE but now its a major problem, as you can see (link removed due to possible malware; see history for link).

Firefox, Chrome, Safari are great, including the latest version of IE I think, but IE 7 does not show the scroll bar or page down.

Any ideas what could be making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm scared to help simply because when I go to your site I get a suspected malware warning. Perhaps that's an issue you should fix first.

[Google Warning](http://google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?tpl=safari&site=jL.chura.pl&hl=en-us)

Perhaps this answer is out of place but is an important notice. 
Is there a reason you have **jl.chura.pl/** in a hidden iframe?

Comment: My virus scanner removed the malicious file, it was a webkit.

Comment: What does this mean?! You've got me really worried here

Comment: Ive never seen this before, Im going through my site now in order to erradicate it, its at the bottom of every file in my site, Ive been hacked I think

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you got nailed by some malware. Change any and all passwords associated with your site, stat. Also, in your Wordpress admin section, *make sure that any and all modules in your layout are clean*.

Comment: Seems like my computer has been infected with a virus, thanks guys for noticing, Im going to have to clean my computer and see where I can go from there

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `div` tag. To debug, I'd grab the source of the page, dump it in an editor, and begin deleting matching `<div>...</div>` sets.

Also, remember that `id` attributes are unique to the entire document. You have a few duplicates and that's going to cause you problems as well.